# Perl Regular expression matching with unwanted pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I am new in Perl programming, Please help me out.

I 've to search a pattern and modify it,
The pattern is

`FATAL_ERROR(TRACE_ERROR, "any format string", arguments);`

This is how I m searching the pattern

```
while(/(FATAL_ERROR\s*\(\s*([A-Za-z0-9_\s\|\(\).\[\]]+)[\\,\s]+((\".*?\"\s*\\*\s*)*)[^"]*?;)/sgm)
```

But the prob is, script starts matching the regex with this also

```
MACSIM_FATAL_ERROR(TRACE_ERROR, "format string", arguments);
```

Please suggest me any solution.

Comment: Add a space to your regex in front of the FATAL?

Answer (score 1):

Anchor your search to the to match from the start of the line by adding a ^ character

```
while(/(^FATAL_ERROR\s*(\s*([A-Za-z0-9_\s\|().[]]+)[\,\s]+((\".?\"\s\*\s*))[^"]?;)/sgm)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a word boundary `\b` in front of your regex.

```
while (/(\bFATAL_ERROR\s*\(\s*([A-Za-z0-9_\s\|\(\).\[\]]+)[\\,\s]+((\".*?\"\s*\\*\s*)*)[^"]*?;)/sgm)
```

If you wanted to be more restrictive, like anchoring to the beginning of the string using `^`, you could do that.  But the above is all you'd need to ensure `FATAL_ERROR` is a bounded word.

Note: did not analyze the rest of your regex, although I suspect it could be simplified/improved.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not the first item on the line, but has white spaces before the string (based on user1717159 answer), then add a match for whitespace (\s+):

```
while(/(^\s+FATAL_ERROR\s*(\s*([A-Za-z0-9_\s\|().[]]+)[\,\s]+((\".?\"\s\*\s*))[^"]?;)/sgm)
```

to match the white space or 
can you add a condition to check for the offending string such as:

```
while((/(^\s+FATAL_ERROR\s*(\s*([A-Za-z0-9_\s\|().[]]+)[\,\s]+((\".?\"\s\*\s*))[^"]?;)/sgm) &&
     ( ! /MACSIM_FATAL_ERROR/ ))
```